# Phonegap Barcode Scanner failed Jasmine error

Tags: android, cordova, jasmine, barcode-scanner

I wrote an app using PhoneGap build. It's a barcode scanner. 
After I create the project and add the barcode plugin  ( from the root directory.. `cordova plugin add com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner`)

```
scan : function() {
console.log('scanning');
var scanner = cordova.require("com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner.barcodescanner");
//var scanner = cordova.require("cordova/plugin/BarcodeScanner");

    scanner.scan(function(result) { ..... }
```

After I build the app with PhoneGap Build and tested on my smartphone I got this error: 
[image]

What can I do to solve this error? I think I added the barcode plugin!?

How my index.html file looks like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="barcodescanner.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay guys. I'm done with this error. 
I installed the my project the android platform (cordova platform add android) than installed the barcodescanner plugin with plugman. 
And the error ins gone. :))